# Flying back to EU with electronic devices without being able to prove I already paid VAT and import taxes

Tags: electronic-items, import-taxes, vat

I'm a French resident.

In 2019 I bought online a $200 laptop coming from Hong-Kong. It was sold by the merchant without VAT and sent by DHL. I remember very well I had to pay around 55 euros in VAT + custom taxes on the DHL website in order to get my shipment delivered to me.

It seems I made the mistake to delete all my emails concerning this device. I have absolutely no proof anymore that I paid the VAT and other taxes. I don't even have the invoice from the merchant anymore.

Now the thing is, I'd like to travel outside EU with this device. So the question is: When reentering EU (France) do I risk paying VAT and import taxes a second time if I'm not able to prove that I already paid them?

I want to travel with 2 laptops in total and several other electronic devices but I'm worried they ask me to pay for things I already paid for…

Comment: Are you still in France?

Comment: Yes still living in France but traveling in Asia next month and coming back with a transit through Turkey

Comment: In practice, nobody ever looks at an obviously used laptop, also not if you carry two. Nowadays, they look at you funny if you _don't_ have a laptop with you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When reentering EU (France) do I risk paying VAT and import taxes a second time if I'm not able to prove that I already paid them?

In theory, yes, the burden of proof is on you. That said, there are several reasons not to be concerned in your case. $200 is within the duty free allowance for personal use. It does not apply when you order by mail (which is why you had to pay in 2019) but it does apply if you're bringing something with you, making the question moot. On top of that, a laptop from 2019 has already lost much of its value. Things would be different if we were talking about a newish Apple device.

All that assumes your other devices have been bought in France / the EU or properly imported and are otherwise unremarkable, the allowance applies to everything you're importing into the EU, not device-by-device.

Comment: As OP travels with several devices, is there a real concern that the total value runs a trigger?

Comment: @Willeke Not sure I undersand your question, what do you mean?

Comment: OP will not have just the one laptop but also more expensive items. I wonder whether a high total can give a problem with his older laptop.

Comment: Well, actually the price of this laptop even increased because of the component shortage making their price higher. It's now sold for $219. As for my other laptop and electronic devices they were all bought outside of EU because I was living abroad and came back to France in 2019. So this $200 laptop is the only one I've actually paid VAT + import taxes. Just that I can't prove it... I think it would be better if I don't bring it. I don't want to look like someone coming back with too many electronic things with me. Especially laptops without French keyboards...

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that's what the last sentence of th answer is about. But if those laptops were bought in France or you have documentation about them, there is no problem.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Customs valuation is a very complex subject and I am not familiar with it but I don't think the price of a similar laptop sold today is directly relevant. In any case, $219 is well within the limit (€430 if travelling by air) so I wouldn't worry. Aganju's comment is also relevant.

Comment: The thing is, this is only my very cheap Linux laptop but I wanted to travel with another more expensive one as well as 2 phones (cheaper to repare them in Asia). And as you said, it's the total value that is counted, not devices individually... So the price I'll be carrying is way more than 430€. Thanks for your answer, at the end I think I'll avoid taking this laptop

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL The total value *of the things you are importing* (and, by extension, the things you cannot prove are not new like this laptop). Again, if you have documentation for the other items, they do not count towards the total.

Comment: Now, if you have no way to prove where you got any of your electronics that's another question but since you specifically mentioned this laptop, that's what I commented on.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this brochure](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/trouble_free_travel_with_french_customs-2.pdf) (pdf) from the French Customs ministry, you can:

> To spare you the trouble of carrying all these documents [receipts, warranty cards, etc.], and to
> facilitate customs clearance of your personal belongings, you may
> obtain a single document called the free circulation card*. The free
> circulation card is free of charge, valid 10 years from date of issue
> and renewable. You can obtain one at any customs office by presenting
> your belongings together with supporting documents (invoices, customs
> receipts, warranty certificates, etc.). As and when you purchase new
> items, you may have additional entries listed on your card by applying
> to the same office that issued the original card.

This may not help with the laptop if the customs office doesn't accept it, but might exempt other devices so that you're under the tax-free limit.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of this free circulation card. However I think the wiser thing now is just to take the habit of scanning those documents and be able to show them at the custom if needed...